# Problem connecting nodes from and axis environment and using /tikz/scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider this almost-MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[clip=false,
    width=12cm, height=12cm,
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=-1, ymax=11,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50, dashed},
    ytick={-1,...,11},
    xlabel = {input voltage $E$ (V)},
    ylabel = {output voltage $v_o$ (V)}, % clip=false,
] 
\draw [thick, ->] (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: 10,0) node[below left] {$E$};  
\draw [ultra thick, color=blue, draw opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 0, 10) -- (axis cs: 0.7, 10) -- (axis cs: 1.6, 0.9) -- (axis cs: 10,9.3);
\draw[ultra thick, color=blue, ->] (axis cs: 4,3.5) -- node [above]{$v_o$} (axis cs: 3,3.5);
\fill [black!50, fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 0, 10.5) rectangle node[black](off){A} (axis cs:0.7, 11);
\fill [green!50, fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 0.7, 10.5) rectangle node[black](lin){B} (axis cs:1.6, 11);
\fill [red!50, fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 1.6, 10.5) rectangle node[black](sat){C} (axis cs:10, 11);
\end{axis}
\path (2,13) node[rectangle, draw](off text){OFF zone};
\path (4.5,12) node[rectangle, draw](lin text){LINear zone};
\path (7,11) node[rectangle, draw](sat text){SATuration zone};
\path [<-] (off.center) edge[bend left] (off text.west);
\path [<-] (lin.center) edge[bend left] (lin text.west);
\path [<-] (sat.center) edge[bend left] (sat text.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives the correct output --- I know that the position of node `(sat)` is not ideal, but I will fix that after I understood this puzzle:

[image: graphic ok]

The problem is that if I add `[scale=0.8]` to the main `tikzpicture` environment, what happens is the following (excerpt of the upper part of the drawing, to save space:

[image: Bad graphic]

It's like if, although the nodes are correctly moved (see the A, B, C labels in the colored band), when I try to connect the nodes from inside the axis to outside something break.

I suppose it's, as ever, an operator error... but which one? It is possible to easily fix it?

PS --- I am using Ubuntu 14.04, with TeXLive2013, and the maximum `pfgcompat` accepted is `1.9`.

PPS (later) --- I can express all in `axis cs:` coordinate, but this will work only if `clip=false`; if I need to clip the axis environment that approach will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are caused by the different coordinate systems, I believe. Therefore I moved the `\path`-commands into the `axis` environment and adjusted their position slightly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[clip=false,
    width=12cm, height=12cm,
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=-1, ymax=11,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={black!50, dashed},
    ytick={-1,...,11},
    xlabel = {input voltage $E$ (V)},
    ylabel = {output voltage $v_o$ (V)}, 
] 
\draw [thick, ->] (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: 10,0) node[below left] {$E$};  
\draw [ultra thick, color=blue, draw opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 0, 10) -- (axis cs: 0.7, 10) -- (axis cs: 1.6, 0.9) -- (axis cs: 10,9.3);
\draw[ultra thick, color=blue, ->] (axis cs: 4,3.5) -- node [above]{$v_o$} (axis cs: 3,3.5);
\fill [black!50, fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 0, 10.5) rectangle node[black](off){A} (axis cs:0.7, 11);
\fill [green!50, fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 0.7, 10.5) rectangle node[black](lin){B} (axis cs:1.6, 11);
\fill [red!50, fill opacity=0.5] (axis cs: 1.6, 10.5) rectangle node[black](sat){C} (axis cs:10, 11);
\path (axis cs: 2,13) node[rectangle, draw](off text){OFF zone};
\path (axis cs: 3.5,12) node[rectangle, draw](lin text){LINear zone};
\path (axis cs: 7,12) node[rectangle, draw](sat text){SATuration zone};
\path [<-] (off.center) edge[bend left] (off text.west);
\path [<-] (lin.center) edge[bend left] (lin text.west);
\path [<-] (sat.center) edge[bend left] (sat text.west);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now the `scale` key works as intended (`0.8` vs `1.5`):

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works --- but I have another graphic where I need to use `clip=true` and this will make this solution impossible. The problem is that I can't understand *why* it happens; coords should be scaled the same way...

Comment: I don't really know _why_ either. All I know is, that `pgfplots` does some pretty sophisticated things in its `axis` environment. For example: All text produced inside it is affected by `scale`, which is not the standard behaviour of `TikZ`. Therefore I recommend not to use `axis` besides regular code in the same `tikzpicture`. Maybe you could put two `tikzpicture`s separated by some `hspace` in a single `figure`?